# WebExcpetion usind WebRequest.BeginGetResponse

Tags: c#, windows-phone, webrequest, system.net.webexception

i have a question which is bothering me for a long time.

I am using Windows Phone 8 and c#.

From time to time I get this Excpetion while downloading a file from the web:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
ExceptionMessage:The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

But then I run the programm again and it works fine. I don't know why it can't find the remote server sometimes, is the problem really with the server?
It think its something in my code, i use these functions:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http...);
IAsyncResult res = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(DownloadComplete), null);
```

I would be grateful for any advice, because this Exception keeps popping up and I couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't say it can't find the remote server, but that the server balked at the file requested because it didn't exist on that remote server *at that time*. It's hard to know your exact scenario, but putting aside network issues, it could be something as simple as *the file doesn't exist, at that point in time*.

How often is this file being updated, if ever? Think of the possibility that, at the time you request the file, it has been deleted and will momentarily be rewritten.

The web isn't inherently reliable and is only made to look reliable; there are numerous techniques in this, but what I'm saying is that, in your case, it might be worse some 'recovery' logic to *try again* upon failure after a period.

Just a possibility.

Comment: THanks for your answer. I already have some logic installed, that will retry downloading if it fails the first time. But when these exceptions are not really my fault, how do I hide them? Is there any way I can stop them from being displayed in my debugger window?

Answer (score 0):

I get this when I forget the phone is running in an emulator and change the web reference to localhost. Localhost will then be interpreted on the phone itself and obviously the web service isn't running on the phone. If you are doing local debugging, make sure to use your machine's IP address and not localhost or 127.0.0.1.